# How do I add conditions to a row number over partition by statement

Tags: sql, hive, row, case, partition

I am trying to assign a top store to clients based on total sales, and then just by country sales.

I realize i could probably get this if I create a new sales field but just trying to save time.  Thoughts?

See below for the code i am using

```
select client_id
      ,region
      ,country
      ,row_number() over(partition by clientid order by sales desc) as rank
      ,case when region='US' then row_number() over(partition by sas_id order by  sales desc) else 0 end as usrank

ClientID Region Store   sales   Rank    USRank1 USRank 2
A        US     20      100     2       2       1
B        US     30      5       6       6       2
C        CA     100     20      4       0       0
D        CA     120     10      5       0       0
E        MX     200     300     1       0       0
F        MX     230     50      3       0       0
```

Comment: edit your question....

Comment: The table you have posted is your expected result or data snippet? If data snippet then post expected result and if expected result then post data snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need a sum(), grouped by country in the second case.

```
SELECT client_id,
       region,
       country,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY sales DESC) AS RANK,
       sum (sales) OVER (PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY sales DESC) as CNTRY_RANK
```